# sorting tr elements with nested tables, hide nested tbody while sorting

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I've got a ...very... nested set of tables.

Here's my DOM:

```
<table id="sortable">
    <thead>...</thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="draggable_item">
            <td>
                <table>
                    <thead class="show_this_while_dragging">...</thead>
                    <tbody class="hide_this_while_dragging">
                        <tr>
                            <td>...</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Each tr in table#sortable is draggable. When it's being dragged, I want to hide the tbody in the table inside *each* tr.draggable_item.

Here's how I initialize my sortable:

```
$( selector ).sortable({
    helper: fixHelper
});

$( selector ).sortable( "option", "start", function(event, ui) { start_callback(selector) } );

function start_callback(selector)
{
    $(selector + " table tbody").hide();
}
```

This works almost as expected. Each tbody disappears, even the one that is being dragged. But there's extra space where the tbody was in the currently dragged item.

I am not sure what's causing it, or how to remove it. The height of the tr.draggable_item that is being dragged is locked as soon as I start dragging the item.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ywF9E/3/ - you'll notice here too, that to drag row 1 under row 2, you have to drag it under where the tbody would be if it weren't hidden.

Comment: `detach`ing the elements as opposed to `hide`ing them doesn't seem to have an effect. I believe the problem is with the start event. I think I want something like a beforeStart event.

Comment: My problem is similar to this I think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804238/jquery-ui-sortable-perform-action-before-start-event-fires

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[<kbd>jsFiddle Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/ywF9E/9/)

At first I'd like to say that it's clear you really put effort in finding a solution on your own so it really made me want to help.

The problem is that if you hide parts of the element after it begins to be dragged, the size isn't recalculated.

The solution is like in the code you've linked. You have to catch a more preliminary event (like mousedown) and hide it before the dragging begins.

```
$('tr.draggable_item').mousedown(function() {
       $(this).find("tbody").hide();
    });
$('tr.draggable_item').mouseup(function() {
       $(this).find("tbody").show();
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the compliment, and you are right! That's exactly what I had to do. :]